# If, elseif and else statements returning incorrect results

Tags: php, html, if-statement, routes, require

I am having some problem creating this fail catch in PHP. I want `require 'error.php';` to be shown when a user enters a bad URL, which returns `$echo_error_404 = 1`.
I use normal PHP routing, which means, my URL gets split up into `/example1/example2/example3/`.

I have this page `projects` which is the same as `$routes[1]` when I enter that page. The file `projects.php` does not exist. Understood correctly `projects` should fall in under the second `elseif` statement. And then be given `$error_echo_404 = 1` when `file_exists()` is used. However... for some weird reason it continues all the way into `$echo_content = '<div id="content-wrap">'.$php_doc_html."</div>";`
*PS: Also I know a lot of my code is poorly formatted, however, I did it trying to solve my problem.*

**The code to check what files to require, and run error check:**

```
// FIND WEBSITE CONTENT
$echo_content = "";

if(empty($routes[1])){
    require 'frontpage.php';
    if($echo_error_404 == 0){
        $echo_content = '<div id="content-wrap">'.$front_page_html."</div>";
    }
}
elseif((!empty($routes[1])) && ($routes[1] == "page")){
    require 'frontpage.php';
    if($echo_error_404 == 0){
        $echo_content = '<div id="content-wrap">'.$front_page_html."</div>";
    }
}
elseif((!empty($routes[1])) && ($routes[1] != "page")){
    $php_doc = $routes[1];
    $file_exist = $php_doc.".php";
    if(file_exists($file_exist)){
        require $php_doc.".php";
        if($echo_error_404 == 0){
            $echo_content = '<div id="content-wrap">'.$php_doc_html."</div>";
        }
        if(empty($echo_content)){
            $echo_error_404 = 1;
        }
    }
    else{
        $echo_error_404 = 1;
    }
}
else{
    $echo_error_404 = 1;
```

**This is how I run the correct version if `$echo_error_404 = 1`:**

```
if($echo_error_404 == 1){

    require 'error.php';

    $error_index_head = <<< EOF
    HTML TAG OPENING, TITLE, HEAD AND BODY OPENING ETC.
EOF;

    echo $error_index_head;
    echo $header_html;
    echo '<div id="content-wrap">'.$error_page_html.'</div>';
    echo $echo_index_after;
    echo $footer_html;
}
else{
    echo $echo_index_head;
    echo $header_html;
    echo $echo_content;
    echo $echo_index_after;
    echo $footer_html;
}
```

**This is what I get in the browser as return, clearly showing that `$echo_error_404` was not assigned the value `1`:**

[image: Image of result]

`var_dump()` results:

```
elseif((!empty($routes[1])) && ($routes[1] != "page")){
    $php_doc = $routes[1];
    var_dump($php_doc);

    $php_doc_html = "";
    var_dump($php_doc_html);

    // THE CODE INBETWEEN

else{
    $echo_error_404 = 1;
}

var_dump($php_doc_html);
var_dump($echo_error_404);
```

Return shows that projects is in `$routes[1]` and that `$echo_error_404` is `= 1`:

```
string(8) "projects"
string(0) ""
string(0) ""
int(1)
```

Comment: Would a `switch()` statement work better?

Comment: I haven't tought about that, but still. My code looks correct to me anyways? Should give such a weird output.

Comment: var_dump all the things at each stage. Inside of each if statement and immediately after, var_dump ($echo_error_404); If it's not switching when it should, var_dump the conditions in the if statements before the if statement.

Comment: @Terminus, var_dump() is added.

Comment: You should see where the unexpected occurred.

Comment: @Terminus, Thank you. Problem solved using var_dump() and Twistys solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a bit cleaner to use `switch()`. If we first check that `$routes[1]` is empty or not, we should not need to do it again in later conditions. It does not make sense to me that you then check it agian in your `elseif`. If it was empty, it would satisfy the first `if` and not move on to the next parts of the statement.

```
// Assume no content
$echo_content = "";

// Check for content
if(empty($routes[1])){
    require 'frontpage.php';
    if($echo_error_404 == 0){
        $echo_content = '<div id="content-wrap">'.$front_page_html."</div>";
    }
} else {
    switch($routes[1]){
        case "page":
            require 'frontpage.php';
            if($echo_error_404 == 0){
                $echo_content = '<div id="content-wrap">'.$front_page_html."</div>";
            }
            break;
        default:
            $file_exist = "{$routes[1]}.php";
            if(file_exists($file_exist)){
                require $file_exist;
                if($echo_error_404 == 0){
                    $echo_content = '<div id="content-wrap">'.$php_doc_html."</div>";
                }
            } else {
                $echo_error_404 = 1;
            }
    }
}
if(empty($echo_content) || $echo_content == ""){
    $echo_error_404 = 1;
}
```

Comment: Each of the require pages set the value of `$echo_error_404` to 1 if problems appear. Therefor I need to have the preset to `$echo_error_404 = 0`. I can assume no content tough.

Comment: I noticed that, I adjusted it.

Comment: Tried your answer. Still not working. However, using var_dump on my own solution I can see that ``$echo_error_404` is being set. For some reason it just wont run the correct statement...

Comment: I ran another var_dump. Figure out something... I used var_dump before and after footer.php. It was set before and unset after. Checking it now.

Comment: Sweet, just updated the files and your solution worked! :)